# Is it possible to access Javascript's built-in Date object in Bixby Action Javascript?

Tags: bixby

Ultimately, I'm trying to get the user's day of year, but `var now = Date()` raises `ReferenceError: "Date" is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer turned out to be: *No, it was purposely removed*.

However, as of ~February 25, 2019, **Bixby added support for the native Javascript Date object back into the SDK**.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/sdk.2019-Q1-SDK-Release-Notes#allowed-javascript-date-object

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011434854-Why-do-I-have-to-use-Bixby-s-DateTime-library-instead-of-Javascript-s-Date-reference-) is the reason for error.

You have to use bixby Date here not JS which can be found [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.datetime) with example.

Comment: I saw that, but Bixby Studio tells me `viv.time` is deprecated? More importantly, I'm not really looking to see how a user can *represent* a date through NL... only in retrieving the user's current datetime (I noticed it can be overwritten in the simulator, but no idea how to get it).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this?

https://github.com/petehaas/bixby.playground.javascript

Answer (score 0):

Bixby's built-in library "dates" has a function called getDateTime that might help for now. See if this helps. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/dates